# 2 Pieces of Data in a single Cell of a List Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java, coming from Python. I am looking to make a list that can hold coordinates x and y into a single cell of a list so that when I make a for loop, it will iterate over both x and y simultaneously and then go on to the next x and y coordinates.

In Python it looked something like this:

myList = [ [1,2], [3,2], [3,5], [3,8] ]

So cell 0 would be 1,2... and cell 0 of cell 0 would be 1.
cell 1 would be 3,2... and cell 0 of 1 would be 3
and so on...

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I have been scratching my head at this one for a while.

Comment: Can you please mark answer as accepted if your problem was solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java supports nested arrays just like Python, so you can have exactly the same thing with a bit different declaration. Here's how you can do it in Java

```
int[][] arr = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 8}};
System.out.println(arr[1][0]);
```

Give output `2`. We call them two dimensional arrays.